# Automatically determining the mouse sensitivity

Tags: unity, mouse

I have a 3D game. The player can rotate the character left+right using the mouse, and move the character  forward+backward using the keyboard. The problem is how to set the speed in which the mouse movement rotates the character. Different players have very different preferences, probably due to the sensitivity of their own mouse.
There is an in-game button that allows players to change the mouse sensitivity, but is there a way to determine it automatically?

Comment: Are you asking how a computer program could read the player's mind to determine what sensitivity they prefer, without asking them to choose that preference explicitly?

Comment: @DMGregory not exactly read the player's mind, but read the player's actions. For example, the program can notice that the player rotates left and right quickly, and fails to stabilize, and deduce that the mouse sensitivity is too high - the mouse moves too quickly for the player.